# Factorization of ideal of a quotient ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

Consider the ring $R=\mathbb{C} [x, y] /(f(x, y)) $ where $f(x, y) =y^2-x(x^2-1)$. Is there any systematic way to determine factorization of ideal generated by (image of) $x-2$ in $R$?

Just some hints for computation are sufficient.

Comment: $(x-2)=(y-\sqrt 6)(y+\sqrt 6)$.

Comment: In this case "systematic way" can only mean to substitute $2$ in $y^2-x(x^2-1)$ and get $y^2-6$ which decomposes as $(y-\sqrt 6)(y+\sqrt 6)$. This looks intuitive, but can also check it and convince yourself that the answer is correct.